# click python how can i read json like argument from command line

Tags: python, shell, command-line-interface, python-click

my issue is that I want to perform something similar to what [httpie](https://httpie.org) does. Example

```
cli foo:='["http","pie"]'
```

What I have done in my code is this

```
@click.command()
@click.argument('options', nargs=1)
def dummy(options):
    key, value = options.split(':=')
    click.echo({key: json.loads(value)})
```

For test, I have tried the following commands in my shell:

`$ ibc dummy star:="{"foo":"bar"}"` and
`$ ibc dummy star:={"foo":"bar"}` (I have a Windows 10 machine)

I get a `json.JSONDecodeError`. Can somebody helps me to debug this issue?

The stack trace is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\rolla\.virtualenvs\infoblox_client-tZbB1-ed\Scripts\ibc-script.py", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('infoblox-client', 'console_scripts', 'ibc')()
File "c:\users\rolla\.virtualenvs\infoblox_client-tzbb1-ed\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 764, in __call__
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\rolla\.virtualenvs\infoblox_client-tzbb1-ed\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 717, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "c:\users\rolla\.virtualenvs\infoblox_client-tzbb1-ed\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1137, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "c:\users\rolla\.virtualenvs\infoblox_client-tzbb1-ed\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 956, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "c:\users\rolla\.virtualenvs\infoblox_client-tzbb1-ed\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "d:\projets\python\infoblox_client\infoblox\scripts\__init__.py", line 31, in dummy
click.echo({key: json.loads(value)})
File "C:\Users\rolla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\rolla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\rolla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Comment: It sounds like the problem may be with the input you're providing- could you post your input as well?

Comment: I updated my post @UnsolvedCypher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because your strings aren't properly escaped. For example, when you enter `"{"foo":"bar"}"`, Python just sees a string `"{"` followed by the unclear letters `foo` then by another string `":"` and so on. Normally in Python, if you want to include quotes in a string, you can either put single quotes in double quotes (like `"He said 'hello' to me"`), put double quotes in single quotes (like `'He said "hello" to me'`), or escape the quotes with a backslash (like `"he said \"hello\" to me"`). In this case, you have to use the last option since it's expecting double quotes in both places:

`$ibc dummy star:="{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"`

Comment: Thank you very much @UnsolvedCypher. I checked and under linux I don't have this problem. Argh this windows! ^^